# No datas showing in Flurry Realtime

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

I'm sending datas to Flurry (Unity, iOS, XCode). No clue why I don't have any activity in the realtime dashboard. I used the latest SDK.

I triple-checked my API key.
Any idea ?

The XCODE log (seems to send datas) :

```
2020-03-21 12:40:42.843425+0100 speedyboarding[1287:418400] -[FlurryStreamCoreBuffer streamMessage:]: msg = <FlurryStreamReporting: 0x281692bc0, type = 164, json = {   "fl.continue.session.millis" : 10000,   "fl.initial.timestamp" : 1584784908367,   "fl.session.event" : "SESSION_PAUSE",   "fl.session.timestamp" : 1584790842841,   "fl.session.state" : 0 }>
-> applicationDidEnterBackground()
```

The unity script :

```
using UnityEngine;

using FlurrySDK;

public class FlurryStart : MonoBehaviour
{

#if UNITY_ANDROID
    private readonly string FLURRY_API_KEY = FLURRY_ANDROID_API_KEY;
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
    private readonly string FLURRY_API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxx";
#else
    private readonly string FLURRY_API_KEY = null;
#endif

    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize Flurry once.
        new Flurry.Builder()
                  .WithCrashReporting(true)
                  .WithLogEnabled(true)
                  .WithLogLevel(Flurry.LogLevel.LogVERBOSE)
                  .WithAppVersion("0.2.5")
                  .Build(FLURRY_API_KEY)


    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please send over the full console log to support@flurry.com and I'll have a closer look.